# CSS - Images side by side in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, alignment

I have tried using the code provided at http://jsfiddle.net/heera/X3b5g/1/, and when I input my own variable names/images in the fiddle it works fine.

But I then put the CSS code into my child theme style.css and the HTML in my page and the images show one on top of the other, not side by side as I need.  I'm not using variables that could be clashing and I'm driving myself insane with this - it is something in Wordpress that stops this from working.

```
.my-side-by-side {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 50px;
}

#my-button-centred {
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="my-button-centred">
  <a href=""https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/belize-travel-guide-paid/id792977226?mt=8">
  <img class="my-side-by-side" border="0" alt="" src="http://hotguidebelize.com/wp-content/uploads/apple-store.png" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app_belizeguide.layout">
  <img class="my-side-by-side" border="0" alt="" src="http://hotguidebelize.com/wp-content/uploads/google-store.png"/></a>
</div>
```

If I take out the div id and just use the div class, I do get the buttons side by side, but then they are not centred.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any styles that will possibly override it in your WP theme? If you check the element with inspector, what does it say? Are the computed styles the same from the example you have provided above?

Comment: I've checked all the styles with firebug and nothing! I've "fudged" it by putting a third transparent button on the left hand side, forcing the two I want further over.  Certainly not ideal but I can't waste another day on two buttons!  The page is http://hotguidebelize.com/belize-at-your-fingertips/ if anyone wants to look and can see something obvious that I haven't - thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly in fiddle: [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/X3b5g/330/)

Can you check the source code while testing it, and make sure no other styles overwriting it?,
if so try adding `!important` in the end of overwrited styles

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a child theme you have to be mindful of any CSS from the parent theme. You may have to override some things from the parent theme.

some examples might be

- margins
- padding
- position
- display

You will have to inspect the element to see every CSS value that is being set that is not in your child theme and find which one(s) are causing it to display improperly.

Comment: this is IMO the biggest downfall to using child themes.